# OnItemClick Listener and the visibility of the clicked View item

Tags: android, listview, view, onitemclicklistener

I have a ListView that each item contains one `Textview` and `ImageView` which the `imageView` is `invisible` and by clicking the each listview item it will be `visible` my code is :

```
 @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    ImageView acceptImageView= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iAccept);
    if (acceptImageView.getVisibility()==ImageView.INVISIBLE) {
        acceptImageView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        acceptImageView.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

`List View adapter :`

```
public class ContentViewrAdaptor extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

private List<String>   originalData = null;
private List<String>   filteredData = null;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Typeface       regular;
private ItemFilter     mFilter      = new ItemFilter();


public ContentViewrAdaptor(Context context, List<String> data, Typeface regular) {
    this.filteredData = data;
    this.originalData = data;
    this.regular = regular;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}


public int getCount() {
    return filteredData.size();
}


public Object getItem(int position) {
    return filteredData.get(position);
}


public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;


    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.text_view, null);


        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contentText);
        holder.text.setTypeface(regular);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (filteredData.get(position).contains("font"))
        holder.text.setText(Html.fromHtml(filteredData.get(position)));
    else
        holder.text.setText(filteredData.get(position));
    return convertView;
}


static class ViewHolder {

    TextView  text;
}


public Filter getFilter() {
    return mFilter;
}


private class ItemFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        final List<String> list = originalData;

        int count = list.size();
        final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);

        String filterableString;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            filterableString = list.get(i);
            if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                filterableString = filterableString.replaceAll(filterString, "<font color='red'>" + filterString + "</font>");
                nlist.add(filterableString);
            }
        }

        results.values = nlist;
        results.count = nlist.size();

        return results;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
}
```

but the problem is that when i accept the first item , the third item will be acceped too , because it's the first item when scroll down

how can i solve this problem ?

**Update(getView)**

but still the same problem

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.text_view, null);


        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iAccept);
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context,position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (v.findViewById(R.id.iAccept).getVisibility() == ImageView.VISIBLE)
                    v.findViewById(R.id.iAccept).setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                else
                    v.findViewById(R.id.iAccept).setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contentText);
        holder.text.setTypeface(regular);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (filteredData.get(position).contains("font"))
        holder.text.setText(Html.fromHtml(filteredData.get(position)));
    else
        holder.text.setText(filteredData.get(position));
    return convertView;
```

}

**Final Update**

finally it solved with DIVA help ,

i changed Adapter to this :

```
public class ContentViewrAdaptor extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

private List<String> originalData = null;
private List<String> filteredData = null;
private ArrayList<Integer> visiblePositions;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Typeface regular;
private Context context;
private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();


public ContentViewrAdaptor(Context context, List<String> data, Typeface regular) {
    this.filteredData = data;
    this.originalData = data;
    visiblePositions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    this.regular = regular;
    this.context = context;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}


public int getCount() {
    return filteredData.size();
}


public Object getItem(int position) {
    return filteredData.get(position);
}


public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.text_view, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iAccept);
        holder.image.setTag(position);
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contentText);
        holder.text.setTypeface(regular);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


    adjustImageVisibility(holder.image, visiblePositions.contains(position));

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onViewClicked(holder, position);
        }
    });

    if (filteredData.get(position).contains("font")) holder.text.setText(Html.fromHtml(filteredData.get(position)));
    else holder.text.setText(filteredData.get(position));

    return convertView;
}

public void onViewClicked(ViewHolder viewHolder, Integer position) {
    if (visiblePositions.contains(position)) {
        adjustImageVisibility(viewHolder.image, false);
        visiblePositions.remove(position);
    } else {
        adjustImageVisibility(viewHolder.image, true);
        visiblePositions.add(position);
    }
}

public void adjustImageVisibility(ImageView imageView, boolean visible) {
    if (visible) imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}


static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView image;
    TextView text;
}


public Filter getFilter() {
    return mFilter;
}


private class ItemFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        final List<String> list = originalData;

        int count = list.size();
        final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);

        String filterableString;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            filterableString = list.get(i);
            if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                filterableString = filterableString.replaceAll(filterString, "<font color='red'>" + filterString + "</font>");
                nlist.add(filterableString);
            }
        }

        results.values = nlist;
        results.count = nlist.size();

        return results;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: View visibility and other properties must be set inside your Adapter `getView()` because of View recycling

Comment: @SimonMarquis you mean i should update my adapter on each item click?

Comment: You should update the data your Adapter is displaying, and then notify your Adapter that data has changed

Comment: where is imageview in ViewHolder  ?

Comment: I don't now how should handle this on adapter , is it possible to tell me what should i do on my adapter?

Comment: Lets discuss on chat

Comment: why you are not implementing that logic in getView() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few thing u need to make sure :

- plz use arraylist instead of static string[]
- use View.Visible or invisible instead of Imagview.Visible and
  invisible while comparing visiblity here is code that works :

**Adapter**

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private ArrayList<String> originalData = null;
    private ArrayList<String> filteredData = null;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context context;

    private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();

    public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> data) {
        this.filteredData = new ArrayList<>(data);
        this.originalData = new ArrayList<>(data);
        this.context = context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return filteredData.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return filteredData.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            // holder.image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        // holder.image.setTag(position);
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (v.findViewById(R.id.image).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    v.findViewById(R.id.image).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    v.findViewById(R.id.image).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }
        });
        if (filteredData.get(position).contains("font"))
            holder.text.setText(Html.fromHtml(filteredData.get(position)));
        else
            holder.text.setText(filteredData.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;
        TextView text;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        return mFilter;
    }

    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            final ArrayList<String> list = originalData;

            int count = list.size();
            final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);

            String filterableString;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                filterableString = list.get(i);
                if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                    filterableString = filterableString.replaceAll(
                            filterString, "<font color='red'>" + filterString
                                    + "</font>");
                    nlist.add(filterableString);
                }
            }

            results.values = nlist;
            results.count = nlist.size();

            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {
            filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView listView;
    private ListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        ArrayList<String> LIST_ITEM = new ArrayList<String>();
        LIST_ITEM.add("Item 1");
        LIST_ITEM.add("Item 2");
        LIST_ITEM.add("Item 3");
        LIST_ITEM.add("Item 4");
        LIST_ITEM.add("Item 5");
        LIST_ITEM.add("Item 6");
        LIST_ITEM.add("Item 7");
        LIST_ITEM.add("Item 8");
        LIST_ITEM.add("Item 9");
        LIST_ITEM.add("Item 10");

        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        adapter = new ListAdapter(MyActivity.this, LIST_ITEM);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

[COMPLETE SOURCE CODE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hbyctmcv469xrh0/Demo.tar.gz?dl=0)

EDIT
[ALTERNATIVE CODE.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/973elnf9l331fi6/CheckBoxProblem.rar?dl=0)

Comment: i test it right now , and unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: chk alternative code u need todo this way, let me know via comment if any issues

Comment: on this example we have a checkbox on convertview and on this question we want to make it to work for convertview on click listener

Comment: correct but this is what the idea u need to do with convertview...if this didnt helped? then u need to expain in u demo rather...

Answer (score 0):

For each list item you would need to create a `boolean` parameter `isVisible`. And set it to true/false on the click of the list item. Within the `getView()` method check the `isVisible` value of each visible item:

```
if(isVisible)
   make the image visible;
else 
   hide the image;
```