# set the View of button and checkbox list to GONE

Tags: android

I am creating a checkbox list with a button programmatically. For updating purpose I need to delete the old checkbox list and button before creating the new one in the delete_`element method`. How can I set their visibality to `GONE` in the `delete_element` method? How can I check whether they are already exist or not before set them to `GONE`? How can I get their id in the `delete_element` me

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference

code in the MainActivity:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> items = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     LinearLayout ll;
    .
    .
    .
    .
    @Override
    public void onAsyncTaskFinished(ArrayList<Integer> result) {

        remove_elements();
        createCheckboxList(result);


    }

    private void remove_elements() {
        for (int i : items) {
            CheckBox ch = (CheckBox) findViewById(i);
            ch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(1);
        btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    private void createCheckboxList(final ArrayList<Integer> items) {
        this.items = items;
        final ArrayList<Integer> selected = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lila);
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
            cb.setText(String.valueOf(items.get(i)));
            cb.setId(items.get(i));
            ll.addView(cb);

        }
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500, 150));
        btn.setText("submit");
        btn.setId(1);
        ll.addView(btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    }
}
```

Comment: but why need to delete, just check before adding new data like adapter is not null and having a count if yes than clear adapter and set adapter with new data every time either its a first time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void remove_elements() {
    for (int i : items) {
        CheckBox ch = (CheckBox) ll.findViewById(i);
        ch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    Button btn = (Button) ll.findViewById(1);
    if (btn != null ) {
        btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a Click Listener to the item view (`convertView`) in the `ListView` - If you can click the item it must be visible. Then you can set the convertView to `INVISIBLE` or `GONE` if you want it to be removed completely.

Here's some sample code for you adapters `getView` method

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

final ViewHolder holder;

if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.text_view, null);

    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iAccept);
   ......
    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

//Do this!!
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }
});

...
...
//Set your values here for the ListView.

return convertView;
```

}

You will have to keep an external list of objects, to know which one is `VISIBLE` or `INVISIBLE`

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25465765/onitemclick-listener-and-the-visibility-of-the-clicked-view-item), it has some good ideas